# Insert Formula Field into Database in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I've a formula field in my hbm file. Which is using a User Defined SQL Function. This function generates a sequence number.

```
<property name="RequisitionNo" column="RequisitionNo" formula="Aims.GenerateRequisitionNo()" not-null="true" generated="insert"  />    
<property name="IsReqForCustomerOrder" column="IsReqForCustomerOrder" not-null="true" />
<property name="SalesOrderNo" column="SalesOrderNo" not-null="false" />
<property name="IsActive" column="IsActive" not-null="true" />
```

But When Nhibernate generates insert query its ignoring the formula field. How can I insert sql function generated value into database.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is a `read only` value and cannot be written back to the database.

Surely your answer here is to add `dbo.GenerateRequisitionNo()` as a default on the `RequisitionNo` column and get rid of this formula column, this seems from first glance to be the correct route.